# solve the pde for P(x)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve for $P(x)$ in the pde $$P(x,y)+x \frac{\partial P(x,y)}{\partial x}=K(x,y)$$ where $K(x,y)>0$ and  is $0$ at $x,y=0$.

At least ensure positive definiteness of $P(x)$, if not the solution.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Please don't just state questions, which may appear to be homework questions. Show us what you have done and where you are stuck, and people are more likely to help you

Comment: Hint : Since there is only a derivative with regard to only one variable, this is not a PDE. This is a simple linear ODE. I am sure that you know how to solve such a very simple ODE.